# Xposed: cannot hook KeyguardSimPinView

Tags: android, xposed-framework

I've tried to hook constructors of `KeyguardSimPinView`,`KeyguardViewMediator`, `KeyguardPasswordView` in `initZygote()`.
Only `KeyguardSimPinView` doesn't work.
I use Android 4.2.2
What can cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like KeyguardSimPinView is not used on startup in this ROM, instead KeyguardSimPinPukView is used. 
Hooking KeyguardSimPinPukView constructor works ok